# using EmaiJS, error on service and template ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, bootstrap-4

I am currently experimenting with the EmailJS library, I have followed the documentation to what I thought was 100%, I placed the code in the script tag that is embedded in the head on the  contact.html, when I send the form, I get a error in the console that says "unexcepted", I created a file called sendEmail.js and wired it to my contact.html, and tried it there, here is the issue:

I am being told that my service ID is incorrect, I went, updated it, and then was told my template ID is incorrect too, so I updated that, saved it and tried again, its still not working, please see attached screenshot of the details on my test emailJS account:

Service ID:
[Service ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2QsQ.jpg)

Template ID:
[Template ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFJ8n.jpg)

Here is my contact.html code:
This is my init method in the

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        emailjs.init("user_vanqZMkpPOADQP2iEpqKS");
    })();
</script>
```

Here is my form code:

```
<form onsubmit="return sendMail(this);">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Name" required/>
                <input type="text" name="emailaddress" class="form-control" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email" required/>
                <textarea rows="5" name="projectsummary" class="form-control" id="projectsummary" placeholder="Project Description" required></textarea>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary center-block">Send Project Request</button>
            </form>
```

Here is my sendEmail.js code:

```
// function has one one argument "contactForm"

function sendMail(contactForm) {

const templateParams = {
    "from_name": contactForm.name.value,
    "project_request": contactForm.projectsummary.value,
    "from_email": contactForm.emailaddress.value
};

const serviceID = "service_golcdlt";
const templateID = "template_7qaoafp";

// Service ID, Template ID, template parameters
emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, templateParams)
    .then(
        function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS", response)
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("Error: Unable to send", error)
        }
    );

    return false; // To block from loading a new page
};
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?